# What's the best online resource to learn about installing JSON API's

Tags: php, json

What's the best online resource to learn about installing JSON API's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the most common way to deal with JSON encoding/decoding in PHP is to use the json_encode/json_decode functions that come with (you don't need to install them) PHP 5.2.0 or higher.

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php and pay particular attention to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

If you want to familiarize yourself with the JSON format, have a look at http://www.json.org/